# Appium application is giving null pointer exception if using two or more classes in testng.xml

Tags: java, automation, testng, appium-android, java-client

Appium application is giving null pointer exception if using two or more classes in testng.xml
Attached are the codes below. If I use any one of the class in testng.xml file, it works fine. But if I define both the classes in testng.xml file, it gives null pointer exception. Please help...
Application driver class :

```
package wikipedia_app_setup;

import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;

public class Wikipedia_app_launch {
    //public static AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public WebDriver openWikipedia() throws Exception
    {
        DesiredCapabilities dc=new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.setCapability("deviceName", "Moto g5 plus");
        dc.setCapability("udid","ZY223XXDVV");
        dc.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        dc.setCapability("platformVersion","8.1.0");
        dc.setCapability("app","C:\\Users\\Keshavgoyal\\Downloads\\org.wikipedia.apk");
/*      dc.setCapability("appPackage","com.google.android.calculator");
        dc.setCapability("appActivity","com.android.calculator2.Calculator");*/
        URL url=new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
        driver=new AppiumDriver<MobileElement>(url,dc);
        System.out.println("Application Started");
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    return driver;
}

    @AfterSuite
    public void closeWikipedia() throws Exception
    {
        driver.quit();
}
}
```

First class locators class :

```
package wikipedia_login_page;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class Login_test_elements  {

    //public AppiumDriver<WebElement> driver;

    public WebDriver driver;
    public final String wrongCredentialMessage = "Incorrect username or password entered";

    // Form Elements
    @FindBy(id ="org.wikipedia:id/menu_overflow_button")
    public WebElement menuOverflowButton;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/explore_overflow_account_container")
    public WebElement logOnButton;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/login_username_text")
    public WebElement usernameTextbox;
    @FindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/TextInputLayout[2]/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.EditText")
    public WebElement passwordTextbox;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/login_button")
    public WebElement loginButton;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/snackbar_text")
    public WebElement wrongCredentialToastMessage;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/explore_overflow_account_name")
    public WebElement displayUsername;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//android.widget.ImageButton[@content-desc=\"Navigate up\"]")
    public WebElement navigateButton;

    public Login_test_elements click_menu_overflow_button() {
        menuOverflowButton.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements click_logon_button() {
        logOnButton.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements enter_wrong_username_to_login() {
        usernameTextbox.click();
        usernameTextbox.sendKeys("rite2keshav");
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements enter_wrong_password_to_login() {
        passwordTextbox.click();
        passwordTextbox.sendKeys("rite2keshav");
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements click_login_button() throws InterruptedException {
        loginButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements validate_wrong_credential_message() {
        Assert.assertTrue(wrongCredentialToastMessage.isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertTrue(wrongCredentialToastMessage.getText().contains(wrongCredentialMessage));
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements enter_username_to_login() {
        usernameTextbox.clear();
        usernameTextbox.sendKeys("rite2keshav44");
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements enter_password_to_login() {
        passwordTextbox.clear();
        passwordTextbox.sendKeys("rite2keshav55");
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements click_navigate_button() throws InterruptedException {
        navigateButton.click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements validate_successful_login() {
        Assert.assertTrue(displayUsername.isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertTrue(displayUsername.getText().contains(displayUser));
        return this;
    }

    public Login_test_elements(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
    //  PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);    
    }

}
```

first class test class :

```
package wikipedia_login_page;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import wikipedia_app_setup.Wikipedia_app_launch;

public class Functional_login_tests extends Wikipedia_app_launch {
    public Login_test_elements loginTestElements;

    @BeforeClass
    public void initElementsBeforeClass() {
        loginTestElements = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Login_test_elements.class);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1, groups={"regression"}, description = "Login to wikipedia App with wrong credentials.\n"
            + "1. Click on menu button.\n"
            + "2. Click on logon button.\n"
            + "3. Enter wrong username.\n"
            + "4. Enter wrong password.\n"
            + "5. Click on login button.\n"
            + "6. Validate if app is showing wrong credential message.")
    public void validate_login_to_wikipedia_app_with_wrong_credential() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("##### Current Function ####### " + new Functional_login_tests() {
        }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + "()");
        loginTestElements
            .click_menu_overflow_button()
            .click_logon_button()
            .enter_wrong_username_to_login()
            .enter_wrong_password_to_login()
            .click_login_button()
            .validate_wrong_credential_message();       
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, groups={"regression"}, description = "Login to wikipedia App.\n"
            + "1. Click on menu button.\n"
            + "2. Click on logon button.\n"
            + "3. Enter username.\n"
            + "4. Enter password.\n"
            + "5. Click on login button.\n"
            + "6. Validate if login is success.")
    public void validate_login_to_wikipedia_app() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("##### Current Function ####### " + new Functional_login_tests() {
        }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + "()");
        loginTestElements
            .enter_username_to_login()
            .enter_password_to_login()
            .click_login_button()
            .click_menu_overflow_button()
            .validate_successful_login();       
    }
}
```

Second class locators class :

```
package wikipedia_search_bookmark;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBys;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class Search_bookmark_test_elements {

    public WebDriver driver;

    public final String searchedTitle = "Java";
    public final String bookmarkName = "ProgLangArticles";
    public final String articleAddedMessage = "Added to";
    public final String articleRemovedMessage = "removed from list";

    // Form Elements
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/explore_overflow_account_name")
    public WebElement displayUsername;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/search_container")
    public WebElement searchArticleBox;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/search_src_text")
    public WebElement searchTextbox;
    @FindBys({ @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/page_list_item_container") })
    private List<WebElement> searchedItems;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/view_page_title_text")
    public WebElement searchedItemTitle;
    @FindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.HorizontalScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.Tab[1]")
    public WebElement bookmarkButton;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/onboarding_button")
    public WebElement gotItButton;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/text_input")
    public WebElement bookmarkNameTextbox;
    @FindBy(id = "android:id/button1")
    public WebElement saveBookmarkButton;
    @FindBy(id = "org.wikipedia:id/snackbar_text")
    public WebElement addedToBookmarkListMessage;
    @FindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.ListView/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]")
    public WebElement removeArticleFromListButton;
    @FindBy(xpath = "/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout/android.view.ViewGroup/android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView")
    public WebElement removedFromBookmarkListMessage;

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements click_display_username() {
        displayUsername.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements click_search_article_textbox() {
        searchArticleBox.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements enter_article_to_search() throws InterruptedException {
        searchTextbox.sendKeys("java");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements select_searched_item() throws InterruptedException {
        searchedItems.get(1).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements validate_selected_item_title() {
        Assert.assertTrue(searchedItemTitle.isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertTrue(searchedItemTitle.getText().contains(searchedTitle));
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements click_bookmark_button() {
        bookmarkButton.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements click_gotit_button() {
        gotItButton.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements enter_bookmark_name() {
        bookmarkNameTextbox.clear();
        bookmarkNameTextbox.sendKeys(bookmarkName);
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements click_save_bookmark_button() {
        saveBookmarkButton.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements validate_article_added_to_bookmark() {
        Assert.assertTrue(addedToBookmarkListMessage.isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertTrue(addedToBookmarkListMessage.getText().contains(articleAddedMessage));
        searchedItemTitle.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements click_remove_article_from_list_button() {
        removeArticleFromListButton.click();
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements validate_article_removed_from_list() {
        Assert.assertTrue(removedFromBookmarkListMessage.isDisplayed());
        Assert.assertTrue(removedFromBookmarkListMessage.getText().contains(articleRemovedMessage));
        return this;
    }

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver=driver;
        //PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(driver), this); 
    }
}
```

Second class test class :

```
package wikipedia_search_bookmark;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import wikipedia_app_setup.Wikipedia_app_launch;

public class Functional_search_bookmark_tests extends Wikipedia_app_launch {

    public Search_bookmark_test_elements searchbookmarkTestElements;

    @BeforeClass
    public void initElementsBeforeClass() {
        searchbookmarkTestElements = PageFactory.initElements(driver, Search_bookmark_test_elements.class);
    }

    @Test(priority = 1, groups={"regression"}, description = "Validate search item and its title.\n"
            + "1. Search for an item.\n"
            + "2. Validate searched item title.")
    public void validate_search_article_and_title() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("##### Current Function ####### " + new Functional_search_bookmark_tests() {
        }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + "()");
        searchbookmarkTestElements
        //  .click_display_username()
            .click_search_article_textbox()
            .enter_article_to_search()
            .select_searched_item()
            .validate_selected_item_title();    
    }

    @Test(priority = 2, groups={"regression"}, description = "Validate add bookmark.\n"
            + "1. Search for an item.\n"
            + "2. Add item to bookmark.")
    public void validate_search_article_add_bookmark() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("##### Current Function ####### " + new Functional_search_bookmark_tests() {
        }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + "()");
        searchbookmarkTestElements
            .click_bookmark_button()
            .click_gotit_button()
            .enter_bookmark_name()
            .click_save_bookmark_button()
            .validate_article_added_to_bookmark();  
    }

    @Test(priority = 3, groups={"regression"}, description = "Validate remove article from bookmark.\n"
            + "1. Click on bookmark button.\n"
            + "2. Remove Item from bookmark.")
    public void validate_search_article_remove_bookmark() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("##### Current Function ####### " + new Functional_search_bookmark_tests() {
        }.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() + "()");
        searchbookmarkTestElements
            .click_bookmark_button()
            .click_remove_article_from_list_button()
            .validate_article_removed_from_list();
    }
}
```

Testng.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

    <test name="Functional_login_tests" preserve-order="true" parallel="none" verbose="2">
        <!-- <groups> 
            <run> 
                <include name="regression" 
            </run> 
        </groups> -->
        <classes>
            <class name="wikipedia_login_page.Functional_login_tests" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Functional_search_bookmark_tests" preserve-order="true" parallel="none" verbose="2">
        <!-- <groups> 
            <run> 
                <include name="regression" /> 
            </run> 
        </groups> -->
        <classes>
            <class
                name="wikipedia_search_bookmark.Functional_search_bookmark_tests" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <!-- <test name="Functional_rotate_app_tests" preserve-order="true" parallel="none" 
        verbose="2"> <groups> <run> <include name="preProdSanity" /> <include name="prodSanity" 
        /> <include name="regression" /> </run> </groups> <classes> <class name="wikipedia_rotate_app.Functional_rotate_app_tests" 
        /> </classes> </test> -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
public WebDriver driver;
```

To

```
public static WebDriver driver;
```

**Explain:** So in the above setup both TestNG classes have their own instance of Setup class. TestNG will club `@BeforeSuite` methods from both instances of Setup class as only one while running as a suite. So when the `@BeforeSuite` method runs it initializes the common variable `driver` for the first TestNG class which was consumed by `@Test` methods of the First TestNG class. When the execution of the Second TestNG class begins, `@BeforeSuite` will not be executed again which results in the non-initialization of the very own copy of variable `driver` in SecondTestNGClass and it remains NULL.

Same issue was resolved for me from here [http://makeseleniumeasy...](http://makeseleniumeasy.com/2020/08/09/are-you-getting-nullpointerexception-for-second-testng-test-while-running-as-a-suite/), visit that website for the full explanation with example